# Unable to fetch access token from box or dropbox using mulesoft connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, box

I tried to run the box connector after importing the project from github https://github.com/mulesoft/box-connector
project running successfully but after grant permission, I am getting the following error,

Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: NullPayload

Console Error:

---

ERROR 2015-10-05 13:36:28,731 [[doc-sample].auto-generated-listener-config-0.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
JavaDoc               : http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html
Payload               : {NullPayload}

---

Exception stack is:
1. null (java.lang.NullPointerException)
  org.mule.util.store.PartitionedPersistentObjectStore:105 (null)
2. Unable to fetch access token. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will work fine with version 3.7.2

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<box:config name="Box" clientId="05zpeboxxfms6fo7805izrxff9dwbc74" clientSecret="LVD5juoF7ookFVn4uN69Pco3NI4EQeE0" doc:name="Box">
    <box:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8082" remotePort="8082" path="callback"/>
</box:config>
<objectstore:config name="ObjectStore__Configuration" objectStore-ref="_defaultInMemoryObjectStore" doc:name="ObjectStore: Configuration" />
<flow name="boxAuthenticationFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/auth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <box:authorize config-ref="Box" doc:name="Box-Authorize"  />
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working for me without issues. Anyway below is the my working POC code XML. Give a try with this and note that I am using Mule 3.5.2 run time version

```
<box:config name="Box_Global_Connector" clientId="*********"
    clientSecret="********" doc:name="Box">
    <box:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost"
        localPort="8083" path="callback" remotePort="8083" />
</box:config>
<flow name="mule_box_authorize" doc:name="mule_box_authorize">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8082" path="createFolder" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <logger message="---- Box authorize service triggred" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <box:authorize config-ref="Box_Global_Connector"
        doc:name="Box_Authorize" />
    <box:create-folder config-ref="Box_Global_Connector"
        folderName="Sample_Folder_07Oct2015_v2" doc:name="Box_CreateFolder" />
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using Anypoint Studio - Tooling for Mule ESB Version: 5.3.1 & 3.7.2 run time. In latest version <http:inbound-enpoint> is deprecated. Instead of that http:listener-config is added

Comment: Hi i tried with twitter tutorial from https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-fundamentals/v/3.7/anypoint-connector-tutorial. Same problem "Failed to invoke getUserTimelineByScreenName. Message payload is of type: NullPayload"

Comment: Have you tried with my POC code? Just replace the <http:inbound-endpoint> with <http:listener:config> and run.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. However <http:inbound-endpoint> is deprecated and in newer version it will be removed. So do you have any idea with <http:listener:config>

Comment: I think need to use <http:request>. Do you have any idea about how to use ?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I did a POC on Integrating Mule ESB with Box using Mule Box Connector and made a PPT on this. Just go through the below slidshare PPT for more details

http://www.slideshare.net/RamakrishnaNarkedami/mule-integration-with-box

Also Share your mule config XML code to see where is the issue.

Comment: <box:config name="Box" clientId="${box.clientId}" clientSecret="${box.clientSecret}" doc:name="Box">
        <box:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="8080" remotePort="8080" path="callback"/>
      </box:config>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="authorize">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/auth" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <box:authorize config-ref="Box" doc:name="Box"  />
    </flow>

Comment: Now I am getting the following logINFO  2015-10-07 15:14:09,490 [[box-alfresco].auto-generated-listener-config-0.worker.01] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Current path: null
INFO  2015-10-07 15:14:09,642 [[box-alfresco].auto-generated-listener-config-0.worker.01] org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry: No listener found for request: (GET)/favicon.ico
INFO  2015-10-07 15:14:09,642 [[box-alfresco].auto-generated-listener-config-0.worker.01] org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpListenerRegistry: Available listeners are: [(*)/callback/]

Comment: I will check issue today once I finish my office.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081"  doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>

  <flow name="cookbook-helloworldFlow">
     <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <component class="com.enkindle.Greeting" doc:name="Java"/> 
  </flow>
```